# Pass Props with Link state in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to pass props through `Link` state to a next component but the value is `undefined`.

```
class Weather extends Component {
  state = {
    temp1: undefined
  };

  weatherSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const api_call = await fetch(
      "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&apikey=########################"
    );
    const data = await api_call.json();

    this.setState({
      temp1: data.main.temp
    });
    console.log(this.state.temp1);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-weather">
        <form onSubmit={this.weatherSubmit}>
          <label>Input location Name: </label>
          <input type="text" name="weatherInput" />
          <button type="submit">
            <Link
              to={{
                pathname: "/WeatherResult",
                state: { temp1: this.state.temp1 }
              }}
            >
              Submit
            </Link>
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here `temp1` value is `undefined` where as `console.log` in `weatherSubmit` gives value.

```
class WeatherResult extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.temp1);
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <p>Weather: </p>
        <p>{this.props.temp1}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi aditya, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi Ravi, I tried with location state but it didnt help. I am still getting temp1 value as undefined.

Comment: Can you post your `package.json`?

Comment: react-router-dom is v5 `"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.7.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.2"
  }`

Comment: Hi aditya, check my updated answer and let me know if that helps

Answer (score 3):

When you pass data in `Link` as,

```
<Link
   to={{
       pathname: "/WeatherResult",
       state: { temp1: this.state.temp1 }
   }}
>
```

You can retrieve data in the target component as,

```
this.props.location.state.temp1
```

**Note:** If `this.state.temp1` is a complex object, then it is good to stringify it.

```
<Link
   to={{
       pathname: "/WeatherResult",
       state: { temp1: JSON.stringify(this.state.temp1) }
   }}
>
```

In target component you can retrieve like this,

```
const temp1 = JSON.parse(this.props.location.state.temp1)
```

[Simplified Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sqfv6u)

---

**Update**

If you still get error while accessing `location` object, then it might be possible that you are using `react-router-dom v3`. In this version you need to wrap your component using `withRouter` HOC.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class WeatherResult extends Component { ... }

export default withRouter(WeatherResult)
```

---

**Update 2**

You have wrapped your `button` using `Link`,

```
<button type="submit">
  <Link
    to={{
      pathname: "/WeatherResult",
      state: { temp1: this.state.temp1 }
    }}
  >
    Submit
  </Link>
</button>
```

And you are getting data in `temp1` state variable after you submit the form using `weatherSubmit` function.

So as soon as you click the submit button, it will not block the execution to complete the execution of `weatherSubmit` function and will directly navigate to the target component with path `"/WeatherResult"`. So in this case your `weatherSubmit` function is not getting executed and you'r getting initial value of state in target component i.e. `undefined` (initial state).

The solution is don't wrap button using `Link`, keep it simple button

```
<button type="submit">
   Submit
</button>
```

You can navigate after your `weatherSubmit` function return success and your `temp1` state is successfully set using callback in setState.

```
this.setState({
    temp1: data.main.temp
}, () => this.props.history.push({
     pathname: '/WeatherResult',
     state: { temp1: JSON.stringify(this.state.temp1) }
}));
```

Comment: @Aditya, have you checked this solution? Is it helpful?